# saving strings in las/laz data format

Tags: lidar, las

Can you store stings in las/laz data please? For example every value in point source id is associated with a string label. Can I store that array of strings in a las data format?

Comment: no you can't. Or maybe using a custom VLR to record a table of correspondance

Comment: Thanks! what is a VLR if I may ask please, i have no idea....

Comment: See the specification of the format https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/LAS_1_4_r15.pdf especially see section 2.5